# Tabbed lines setting in TextMate

Tags: tabs, settings, textmate

When a  tabbed line is to long in textmate it shows like this:

[image]

I want it like so:

[image]

Is there a setting in textmate so i can change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a six year old [feature request for this behavior](http://ticket.macromates.com/show?ticket_id=4EFB31A8) in Textmate's ticket system that gets regular "me too" comments, but no signs of being done soon.

Upshot, don't hold your breath.